# Clarification needed for the proof of: Every associate of an irreducible element is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, definition

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $R$ be an integral domain.  Show that every associate of an irreducible element is irreducible

> Proof 1:  Let $a\in R$ be an irreducible element and let $b$ be an associate of $a.$  Then, there exists a unit $u\in R$ such that $a=bu.$  Also as $a$ is non-zero, non-unit, we have that $b$ is non-zero, non-unit.  We now show that $b$ is irreducible element.  Let $b=xy$ for some $x,y\in R.$  Then, $a=bu=xyu.$  Since $a$ is irreducible, either $x$ or $yu$ is a unit.  If $yu$ is a u nit, then there exists some $v\in R$ such that $(yu)v=1.$  This gives that $y(uv)=1$ and so $y$ is a unit.  Thus, either $x$ or $y$ is a unit and hence $b$ is an irreducible element.

> Proof 2:  Suppose $a=bu$ where $b$ is irreducible and $u$ is a unit.  Suppose also $a=xy,$ then $xy=bu$ and hence $b=(bu)u^{-1}=x(yu^{-1}).$  Since $b$ is irreducible, $x$ is a unit or $yu^{-1}$ is a unit.  If $yu^{-1}$ is a unit, say $yu^{-1}v=1,$ then $y$ is a unit.  Therefore $a$ is irreducible.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In both proofs above, don't I have to say or show that $x$ is a unit?  Or in the conclusion of the definition of irreducible element involving a disjunction where it would usually have either "$x$ is a unit or $y$ is a unit."  I only need to show one of the cases to be true and that will be enough?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe the proof would look clearer to you if it said "Since $b$ is irreducible, $x$ is a unit or $yu^{-1}$ is a unit. **If $x$ is a unit we are done.** If $yu^{-1}$ is a unit ..."

Comment: @LukasHegerI still have to show both that $x$ is a unit or $yu^{-1}$ is a unit?

Comment: You have to show that always at least one of $x$ or $y$ is a unit. From the irreducibility of $y$, we deduce that $x$ or $yu^{-1}$ is a unit. Now we make a case distinction: if $x$ is a unit, then clearly it's true that $x$ or $y$ is a unit. If $yu^{-1}$ is a unit, we proceed differently, as the proof does.

Comment: @LukasHeger ah kk, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Easier: associates have the same set of divisors $(d\mid a\mid b\Rightarrow d\mid b)$ so $a$ has a proper factor iff $b$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that always at least one of $x$ or $y$ is a unit. From the irreducibility of $y$, we deduce that $x$ or $yu^{−1}$ is a unit. Now we make a case distinction: if $x$ is a unit, then clearly it's true that $x$ or $y$ is a unit. If $yu^{−1}$ is a unit, we proceed differently to show that $y$ is a unit, as the proof does.